# Javascript string to C# timespan

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime, model-view-controller, timespan

How can I convert javascript time string of

```
var time="10:15:00";
```

to C# timespan property like:

```
public System.TimeSpan Hours { get; set; }
```

I'll pass it as JSON by using ajax call to MVC method. However, the type of property must be the same henve I'll only show the time with the format "hh:mm:ss" as timespan.

Comment: use TimeSpan.Parse(string) method

Comment: This is C# pased. I'm looking for a function to convert from Javascript string to C# TimeSpan type!

Comment: The right string format (that will be parsed into C# TimeSpan) is: {Days}:{Hours}:{Minutes}:{Seconds}.{Milliseconds} So for example, the following string: 01:02:03:04.05 will be parsed into TimeSpan with the following details: 1:Days, 2Hours, 3:Minutes, 4:Seconds, 5:Milliseconds. Please note the colon separators between all the time formats except the milliseconds which is a single dot.